# Check Number Items on List

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

I'm working on a listBox and when I click on the button, I need to display an error message (exactly 30 items on the listBox). But I don't know why the condition doesn't work. I choosed the right method to check the number of Items on the list.

Here is the code.

```
Private Sub btnsSaveDeck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveDeck.Click
    If listBoxDeck.Items.Count < 30 Or listBoxDeck.Items.Count > 30 Then
        MessageBox.Show("BlahBlahBlah", "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for taking time to my problem and have a nice day full of code =)

Comment: `If listBoxDeck.Items.Count <> 30 Then` should be all you need.  If it is not working it is a debugging issue.  Set a breakpoint and use the mouse to see the real number of items,

Comment: um by your description don't u want to check for = 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count = 30 Then
        MsgBox("HEY")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: if any problem tell me